# React JS Typescript input onChange and onFocus error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, typescript-typings

I want to implement the following repo available on Github using ReactJS Typescript. I created 3 different methods as onChange, changeHandler, focusHandler but they are not working correctly. When I click on the Card Number field, I get a 'number.replace' error.

I need to fix onChange and onFocus methods in TextField fields.

https://github.com/amaroteam/react-credit-cards

```
import React, {useState, FocusEvent, ChangeEvent} from 'react'
import Cards from 'react-credit-cards';
import 'react-credit-cards/es/styles-compiled.css'

const PaymentMethodEditor = () => {
  const [stateList, setState] = React.useState(initialValues)

const handleFormSubmit = async (values: any) => {
  console.log(values)
}

const focusHandler = (event: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  setState({ focus: event.target.name })
}

const changeHandler = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  const { name, value } = event.target;
  setState({ [name]: event.target.value })
}

onChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  const newValue = e.currentTarget.value;
 setState({ [name]: event.target.value })
}


return (
 <CustomerDashboardLayout>
  <DashboardPageHeader
    icon={CreditCard}
    title={`${id === 'add' ? 'Add New' : 'Edit'} Payment Method`}
    button={
      <Link href="/payment-methods">
        <Button color="primary" sx={{ bgcolor: 'primary.light', px: '2rem' }}>
          Back to Payment Methods
        </Button>
      </Link>
    }
  />

  <div id="PaymentForm">
    <Cards
      cvc={stateList.cvc}
      expiry={stateList.exp}
      focused={stateList.focus}
      name={stateList.name}
      number={stateList.card_no}
    />
   <Card1>
    <Formik
      initialValues={initialValues}
      validationSchema={checkoutSchema}
      onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}
    >
      {({ values, errors, touched, handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit }) => (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Box mb={4}>
            <Grid container spacing={3}>
            <Grid item md={6} xs={12}>
                <TextField
                  name="card_name"
                  label="Card Name"
                  fullWidth
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                  onChange={changeHandler}
                  onFocus={focusHandler}
                  value={values.card_name || ''}
                  error={!!touched.card_name && !!errors.card_name}
                  helperText={touched.card_name && errors.card_name}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item md={6} xs={12}>
                <TextField
                  name="card_no"
                  label="Card Number"
                  fullWidth
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                  onChange={changeHandler}
                  onFocus={focusHandler}
                  value={values.card_no || ''}
                  error={!!touched.card_no && !!errors.card_no}
                  helperText={touched.card_no && errors.card_no}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item md={6} xs={12}>
                <TextField
                  name="name"
                  label="Name on Card"
                  fullWidth
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  value={values.name || ''}
                  error={!!touched.name && !!errors.name}
                  helperText={touched.name && errors.name}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item md={6} xs={12}>
                <TextField
                  name="exp"
                  label="Exp. Date"
                  fullWidth
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  value={values.exp || ''}
                  error={!!touched.exp && !!errors.exp}
                  helperText={touched.exp && errors.exp}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item md={6} xs={12}>
                <TextField
                  name="cvc"
                  label="CVC"
                  fullWidth
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  value={values.cvc || ''}
                  error={!!touched.cvc && !!errors.cvc}
                  helperText={touched.cvc && errors.cvc}
                />
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Box>

          <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary">
            Save Changes
          </Button>
        </form>
      )}
    </Formik>
    </Card1>
  </div>
</CustomerDashboardLayout>
     )
     }
    const initialValues = {
      card_no: '',
      name: '',
      exp: '',
      cvc: '',
      focus: '',
      number: '',
     card_name: '',
    }
   export default PaymentMethodEditor
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enQ3r.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBdzP.png)